# Ember sendAction from mixin to component without observer. also the mixin import within the component

Tags: ember.js, mixins

Imagine that,

A div-component had button tag and child-component named input-component ( input tag ), input-component contains action for validation. A mixin was import only inside the child component. when i trigger a action from mixin, it calls child-component ( input-comp ) action for getting input value.

Comment: Can you create demo on ember-twiddle.com and be more specific what's expected behavior?

Comment: https://ember-twiddle.com/8ffccad660472740c7484fd36cf53ed6?openFiles=templates.components.dialog-component.hbs%2C

Answer (score 0):

Never try to call an action on a child component. Its not possible! If you try to do it you are doing something wrong!

You should update the data outside and then give down the data. Data down actions up.

Answer (score 0):

You might be missing a service, to get to place where you can manage your state and actions better. So you can try using an actions up, data down approach.

So I went ahead and changed that twiddle of yours to match what I think might still work for your use case.

Have a look at the updated [twiddle](https://ember-twiddle.com/a43a9902c9b62bfa6047d73f6991e281?openFiles=services.domain.js%2C)

Comment: In my scenario, I have more than one component based addon. so, i can't to create service for each addon. no longer need the service because, once i init a component then tne service initialized. ( service is long live ) but, what i need the child action trigger from mixin. ( for replace service usage )